# How to Import MicroSoft Access Database (mdb) into SQL Express File using SQLCMD?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-express, sqlcmd

For some reason neither SQL managment studio nor import and export wizard works on my friends network due to some security policy

i asked a question about OSQL two days ago and StackOverflow guys told me it is going to be obselete and that i should use SQLCMD instead.

now i am stuck with this screen and cant do anything :(

[image]

to cut long things short my question is very precise:

using SQLCMD..

1-need to import and export command from AND to MDB/MDF

2-need attach / detach commands

Comment: I deleted my answer since I misunderstood the question.  I thought you were asking how to run commands from that utility.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mokokamello

below is how to attach new database and make sure your database is attached

[image]

you also will need to check these links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165673.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188031.aspx
AND THE MOST IMPORTANT LINK

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071

if you want to dettach

```
sp_detach_db DatabaseName
Go
```

Comment: The question specifically asked for a MS Access mdb file.  Your links pertain to SQL Server files.

Answer (score 1):

SQLCMD allows you to enter Transact-SQL statements to the chosen server.

The T-SQL command for connecting to an external data source is OPENDATASOURCE

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276845%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

You should be able to construct a series of queries using this in order to pull in, and export the data you are working with.

The SProc to detatch a database is sp_detach_db, and to attach sp_attach_db

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188031.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx) and [here](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-2005/i-want-to-use-sqlcmd-to-detach-a-db-move-a-transaction-log-file-then-reattach-the-db-how-would-i-do-that/)